# Show if $G$ is a planar graph, then $G\setminus e$ is also planar

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, planar-graphs

> Show if $G$ is a planar graph, then graph $G\setminus e$ is also planar.

The exercise is pretty obvious while reading it, but I had some struggles solving it. Using the notation $n=|V(G)|$, $m=|E(G)|$ and $f=|S(G)|$ (number of faces), I thought about proving the statement from Euler's formula, which states that if graph $G$ is planar, then the formula 
$$n-m+f=2$$ is true.

**My proof:** As I need to show the implication, we assume that $G$ is planar, thus $n-m+f=2$. Then we take out one of the edges $e$, so the number of vertices $n$ stays the same, but number of edges and faces is decreased by $1$, so the formula changes to 
$$n-(m-1)+(f-1)=n-m+1+f-1=n-m+f=2$$
which means that the $G\setminus e$ is also a planar graph, which ends the proof.

**Question:** Is my proof correct and sufficient? I also thought about Kuratowski's Theorem, but I do not know how should I solve it then, so any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overthinking it. When you take out one of the edges (which you do as part of your proof), what is left is a drawing of $G\setminus e$ in the plane, ergo it is planar. You don't need to check that Euler's formula still holds.

Comment: As I wrote, I need to prove it, even though it is obvious while thinking about it.

Comment: What I've said is the proof. The definition of planar is that it can be drawn in the plane (without edges crossing). You've shown how to draw it in the plane (take a drawing of $G$, and delete $e$), so it's planar. Everything else is a distraction at best.

Comment: Got it. Even though it is very simple, could I say that as Kuratowski's Theorem states, the graph $G$ is planar iff it does not contain any subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$, then the graph $G \setminus e$ surely does not contain these subdivisions? It is overthinking, but I am trying to get it kind of formal.

Comment: @whiskeyo using an incredibly hard theorem to prove an obvious result is a) ridiculous and b) circular reasoning since the proof of Kuratowski's theorem will have used the fact that if $G$ is planar so is $G\setminus e$. (In fact, that last comment also applies to Euler's formula.)

Answer (score 2):

Euler's formula says that if the graph is planar, then $n-m-f=2$. It does **not** say that if $n-m-f=2$, then the graph is planar.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer makes sense. After all, you can't even define $f$ until you have a drawing of the graph. And it's certainly true that if a plane drawing of your graph satisfies $n-m-f=2$ then the graph is planar!

Comment: Thinking about it, I believe the converse to Euler's formula *is* true: if you have a drawing of a graph (on any surface) which satisfies Euler's formula, then that graph is planar.